# How to use access_token in azure with OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, azure, access-token

I am practicing an azure sample named [OAuth 2.0 Sample for Azure AD Spring Boot Starter Resource Server library for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-resource-server#oauth-20-sample-for-azure-ad-spring-boot-starter-resource-server-library-for-java).I followed the steps but blocked in [Check the authentication and authorization](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-resource-server#check-the-authentication-and-authorization).I have got the access_token successfully, but I don't know how to use it in postman or any other ways. Is there any doc or advice? Thanks very much!

Okay, I added the Authorization in request header, but I got 401 and an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s47Pb.png). And this is way where I got the [access_token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eJfX.png).
Is there something wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do with that access token? Typically you use access token as `Authorization` header value for bearer token authorization. So your authorization header value will be `Bearer <your-access-token>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like below :

You can add the necessary URL and HTTP verb at the top.

You will have to add Authorization **Headers**  in the postman and add the oauth token **bearer** like below

```
Authorization :  Bearer <Oauth Token>
```

[image]

**Update :**

[image]

Comment: (How can I put a picture here ...) I added the Authorization in Headers just like yours , but I got 401 and a error message , `Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"` , I am sure I got the right access_token.

Comment: i think you cannot add pictures in the comment

Comment: If you are testing you could  obtain the access token .. from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Login and check the Access token tab - Updated the screenshot in the Answer

Comment: I reedited this question and added some picture here, could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your endpoint points to something local ? and not an Office 365 resource

Comment: yes, there is a local server which is an azure sample named [azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-resource-server](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-resource-server)